# How do I change the Minimize, Maximize, and Close Button icons?

Tags: windows-11

On Windows 11, is it possible to upload an icon to change a UI button?

- For example, the Minimize/Maximize/Close icons:

   [image: Minimize Maximaze Close]

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: What exactly do you by uploading an icon to a button?

Comment: AFAIK, the ability to do this ceased in Win10+, as Microsoft completely redesigned how accessible these components of the [Windows Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shell) are to users when Win10's UI was changed from Win8's. If it can be done, the only software that would likely be able to do so is Stardock [WindowBlinds](https://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/), but I'm almost positive this is no longer possible on Win10+

Comment: WindowBlinds has a granular UI editor \[[SkinStudio](https://www.stardock.com/products/skinstudio/)] that lists every piece of the Shell that can be customized _([Win8 example](https://imgur.com/a/u5nwTNX))_, and they can either be replaced entirely or image editing software for those specific pieces can be used to edit or recolor them pixel by pixel in Win ≤ 8.1, which allowed editing every piece of the Shell. In Win10, SkinStudio had limited functionality and it's not even included in Win11 from what I can see _(I have WindowBlinds installed)_.